# About average of sequence times average of the inverse of sequence: special case of Reverse Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, integral-inequality

Suppose we have a positive sequence $\{x_i\}$ where $i=1, 2, \dots , n$. And let $m=\mathrm{min}(x_i), \; M = \mathrm{max}(x_i)$. Notice that $m, M>0$.

Prove this inequality (*discrete version*):

$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i }{n} \cdot \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_i} }{n} \le \frac{m+M}{2} \cdot \frac{ \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{M} }{2} \;.$$

Or you can prove this *continuous version*, where $f(x)$ is positive and continuous on $[0, 1]$ , and $m$ and $M$ are min and max values of $f(x)$ on $[0, 1]$, respectively:

$$ \int_0^1 f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x \int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)} \,\mathrm{d}x \le \frac{m+M}{2} \cdot \frac{ \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{M} }{2} \;.$$

**Important:** I do have a proof, because the continuous version is actually an excercise of a workbook of mine. But that proof is too tricky, lacking insight as to why the product of two types of "average"s is controlled by their max and min values. So I brought it up here in seeking of an insightful solution. Hopefully finding a proof directly to the discrete version, for it is easier to imagine with my brain.

**Note:** This question already has answers here [Reverse Cauchy Schwarz for integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879832/reverse-cauchy-schwarz-for-integrals/880365#880365). But that is more of a general case. I am looking for a more insightful and easy-to-understand proof with regard to this specific situation where the $f(x), g(x)$ in the original answer is taken as $f(x), \frac{1}{f(x)}$.

Comment: Please don't repost like this. Further your question is now subjective, what is simpler/ intuitive a proof compared to what's already shown, which is easily specialisable to your case for a "simple" solution. Why don't you attempt the same and say what exactly is complex about it?

Comment: Repeat of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941107/why-this-product-is-no-more-than-the-product-of-the-two-mean-values?noredirect=1#comment8127117_3941107