# Inverse of Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Assume a finite real number sequence $a_i, i=1,\ldots,N$. The following inequality holds true:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^Na_i^2\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\lvert{a_i}\rvert\right)^2\leq N\sum_{i=1}^Na_i^2.
\end{align*}
The RHS inequality is the well-known Cauchy Schwarz inequality. Can the LHS inequality be generalized to Hilbert space like the Cauchy Schwarz inequality? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true in general Hilbert spaces; the LHS inequality would be akin to $\langle x, x \rangle \le \langle x, 1\rangle^2$. Take $H = C^0$ (set of continuous functions) with inner-product $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{1}^{2} f(x) g(x) dx$ and let $f(x) = x$ for a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Suppose $f$ and $g$ are real-valued positive functions. Is there any inequality like $\langle f, g \rangle \geq C \lVert f \rVert \lVert g \rVert$ for some C?

Comment: Yes! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879832/reverse-cauchy-schwarz-for-integrals

This assumes some boundedness conditions, though, you can't have $f$ and $g$ be completely arbitrary.

Comment: @JosephWong There is no such inequality. We may very well have  $\langle f, g \rangle=0$ without $\|f\|$ or $\|g\|$ being $0$.

Comment: @TomChen Your link does not prove any such inequality.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Tom Chen mentions there are boundedness conditions required for the reverse inequality, and those conditions are explicitly stated in the cited question.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose f and g are real-valued positive functions. Is there any inequality like $\langle f,g\rangle\geqslant C\|f\|\|g\|$ for some $C$?

I think it is still wrong even we require $f$ and $g$ are strictly positive ($f,g > 0$).

Let's consider the  real-valued function on closed interval. Such as $[0,1]$. With the linearity of the inner product and norm, it is equivalent to consider the functions with norm $1$ ($\|f\|_{L_2}=1$). Thus the RHS is $C$. It is easy to construct $f$ and $g$, and their inner product $\langle f,g\rangle < C$.