# Reversing AM-GM Inequality When We Have Bounded Variable

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Suppose $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ are positive numbers. Define $A = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, $G = (\Pi_{i=1}^n x_i)^{1/n}$. The well-known AM-GM inequality tells us that
$$
A \geq G
$$

Now suppose we know that each $x_i$ are in the interval $[m, M]$, and $G = (\Pi_{i=1}^n x_i)^{1/n} \in (m,M)$ is given. What is the bound of $A$ in this case?

The lower  bound of $A$ is provided by $G$ again. But I find it hard to give a good estimation of the upper bound of $A$.

The motivation of this is to mimicking the case of Cauchy-Schwarz. There is a well known inequality for Cauchy-Schwarz, such that when we have bounded variables, we can actually find the tight bound for the reverse side. For more information, see [Reverse Cauchy Schwarz for integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879832/reverse-cauchy-schwarz-for-integrals).

Comment: Check this: https://mathoverflow.net/q/122411/116247